# C error about pointer

Tags: c, pointers

Can anyone explain why this code not work, pls!! Thanks you so much!

```
#include <stdio.h>

void changer(char * tp)
{
    int i=0;
    tp[0]='b';
}

int main(void)
{
    char *st="aaab";
    changer(st);
    printf("%s",st);
}
```

Comment: try `char st[]="aaab";`

Comment: When you declare a pointer variable i.e use that ( * ) symbol, you also have to allocate the space that pointer points to. malloc(). If you don't and then use the pointer you are at undefined behavior territory

Comment: @k_kaz when I understood the comments here right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40129319/difference-between-0-and-0 this would be legal

Comment: @KamiKaze: Assigning a string literal to a pointer is not a problem, but trying to modify a string literal is.

Comment: @AleksiTorhamo True enough, but k_kaz didn't point that out. He was talking about the need to allocate it, which is wrong at this point the declaration process works. The modification is the problem as stated by usr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement

```
  tp[0]='b';
```

results in [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because `tp` points to a *string literal*. You are not allowed to modify a string literal in C.

Instead you could use an array:

```
 char st[] = "aaab";
```

which you'd be able to modify.

Comment: thank you mate, i though type a[] & type* is same!

Comment: The difference is that `char *st = "aaab"` puts the *address* of the string literal in the pointer `st`, but `char st[] = "aaab"` actually copies the *contents* of the literal into the array's memory. The second form is equivalent to `char st[5]; st[0] = 'a'; st[1] = 'a'; st[2] = 'a'; st[3] = 'b'; st[4] = '\0';`

Answer (score 0):

```
  char *st="aaab";
```

This statement indicates that st is a pointer variable but "aaab" is string constant.

Instead try

```
  char st[]="aaab";
```

This statement indicates that it declares st as array [5] of char and copies the contents of the string literal. Here st is a constant pointer.

Comment: Tell me whats wrong in above answer

Comment: "st is a pointer variable but "aaab" is [a] string constant": while technically true, this assignment is perfectly allowed in C and what you said doesn't explain OP's problem. As for "This statement indicates that st is [a] pointer constant", that's just not true; it declares `st` as array [5] of `char` and copies the contents of the string literal. usr's answer is correct.

Comment: @trentcl changes incorporated